# Modal windows and binding/unbinding

Tags: jquery, html

I have a modal window that pops up when a "Add New" is selected from the a dropdown.  The user can type in a text field a new option to be added to the dropdown.  It works fine as long as text is actually input each time into each of the new fields (thanks to help from this awesome community [Why does jQuery ajax post twice here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687868/why-does-jquery-ajax-post-twice-here) :-)  Now my problem is that if the user dismisses the modal by clicking outside of it and then selects another "Add New" and attempts to enter text, when the add button is clicked there are a bunch of extraneous actions, just as in the previously linked question above.  Clearly some unbinding needs to be done, but I can't figure it out.  Ideally the user should be able to open and dismiss any number of modal windows and still be able to enter data.  Any ideas?

Here's the jQuery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var Classofentry = '';

        $('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').click(function(){

              // Show modal window
              $('#add-new').modal('show');

              // Get the class
              //var Classofentry = $('#upload_form option[class]').attr("class");
              var Classofentry = $(this).attr("class");
              //console.log(Classofentry);


              $('#add-new-submit').on('click', function(){                

                  // Get new option from text field
                  var value = $('#add-new-text').val();
                  //console.log(value);

                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/change_options",
                        data: {new_option: value, new_option_class: Classofentry},
                        dataType: "html",
                        error: errorHandler,
                        success: success
                      });

                  function success(data)
                  {

                      $('#'+Classofentry).append("<option value='" + data + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data + "</option>"); 
                      //alert(data);

                      //alert('Success!');

                  }

                  function errorHandler()
                  {
                      alert('Error with AJAX!');
                  } 

                  $('#add-new-submit').unbind('click'); // This fixes the problem for multiple entries
                  //$('#add-new-text').unbind('click');
                  //$('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').unbind('click')
                  $('#add-new').modal('toggle');                      

              });

              //$('#add-new-submit').unbind('click');

              //$('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').unbind('click');
        });


  </script>
```

Here's the modal:

```
  <!-- add-new field -->
  <div class="modal small hide fade" id="add-new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-new-fieldLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="add-new-fieldLabel">Add New Field</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <p>Would you like to add a new item?</p>
          <input type="text" id="add-new-text" name="add-new-text" placeholder="Type the new option">

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-new-submit" name="add-new-submit"/>Add</button>
      </div>
 </div><!-- /add-new field -->
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event handler to something that doesn't get replaced in the DOM, ie `<body>`:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#someElement', function() {
    // do something
});
```

You could also bind to another parent tag that you know won't get replaced.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful.  And I've been looking over the documentation on .on but I'm still at a loss about what to use for #someElement.  I've tried #upload_form option[class="addnew"] which doesn't work.  The id of the given element won't change but $('#add-new-submit').on('click', '#upload_form select['#'+Classofentry]', function(){//do something} of course doesn't work.  Can you be more specific?  what do you mean by "get repleced"?  Thanks!

Comment: `someElement` would be the button that's used for the click event. When I mean get replaced, if you have the modal body in a separate file and it's opened with the click like - `$('btn').click(...)` - when that modal is closed the markup of the modal is no longer in the DOM, so jQuery, I think is not binded to the DOM any more. So, if you have a html page, the <body> tag is nearly always going to be there, so binding the click event to it means jQuery won't get unbinded. I'm not an expert on this, but I think this is what may be happening.

Comment: I've tried using $('#add-new-submit').on('click', '#add-new', function(){// do stuff} where add-new is the id in the modal (see above) and $('#add-new-submit').on('click', '#upload_form', function(){//do stuff} where upload_form is the id of the form the jquery and modal are in and in each case it rendered a modal that does not respond to the add button and just stays up.  It seems there's nothing to bind the jquery to.  Any ideas?