# How to have a modal text field not refilled by previous entry

Tags: jquery, html, text, modal-dialog

There's got to be an easy way to do this, but I've tried everything I can think of (which probably doesn't say much).  I have a modal that pops up upon the selection of an "Add New" option in a drop down on the a form.  The first time it pops up the placeholder appears, which is what I want.  But after that, the last entered value appears instead of the placeholder.  How can I have the placeholder appear every time?

Here's the jQuery:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

        var Classofentry = '';

        $('#add-new-text').val() === ''; // Set input text field to blank
        console.log($('#add-new-text').val()); // <--------------- This is filled

        $('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').click(function(){

              // Show modal window
              $('#add-new').modal('show');

              // Get the class
              var Classofentry = $(this).attr("class");
              //console.log(Classofentry);

              //$('#add-new-submit').val() == ''; // Set input text field to blank
              //console.log($('#add-new-submit').val()); // <------------- Empty after first change

              //$('#add-new-text').val() === ''; // Set input text field to blank
              console.log($('#add-new-text').val()); // <--------------- This is filled
              $('#add-new-submit').on('click', function(){                

                  // Get new option from text field
                  var value = $('#add-new-text').val();
                  //console.log(value);

                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/change_options",
                        data: {new_option: value, new_option_class: Classofentry},
                        //dataType: "html",
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: errorHandler,
                        success: success
                      });

                  function success(data)
                  {

                      if (data[1])
                      {
                        // Add new entry
                        $('#'+Classofentry).append("<option value='" + data[0] + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data[0] + "</option>");
                        //alert(data[1]);
                      }
                      else
                      {

                        // Select the nonunique value by emptying it and appending
                        $('#'+Classofentry).empty("<option value=''selected=\"selected\">" + data[0] + "</option>").append("<option value='" + data[0] + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data[0] + "</option>");                                                          
                        //alert(data[0]);                             
                      }

                  }

                  function errorHandler()
                  {
                      //alert('Error with AJAX!');
                      alert(data[0]);
                  } 

                  $('#add-new-submit').unbind('click'); // This fixes the problem for multiple entries
                  $('#add-new').modal('toggle');                      

              });

              //$('#add-new-submit').unbind('click');

              //$('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').unbind('click');
        });


  </script>
```

And the modal:

```
  <!-- add-new field -->
  <div class="modal small hide fade" id="add-new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-new-fieldLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">√ó</button>
        <h3 id="add-new-fieldLabel">Add New Field</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <p>Would you like to add a new item?</p>
          <input type="text" id="add-new-text" name="add-new-text" placeholder="Type the new option">

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-new-submit" name="add-new-submit"/>Add</button>
      </div>
 </div><!-- /add-new field -->
```

As you can see I've tried to simple set the add-new-text tag to blank, which doesn't work.  Is there something I can do in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do

```
$('input').val('');
```

to clear the value ;)

Comment: This worked, but I used $('#add-new-text').val(''); (instead of setting $('#add-new-text').val() == '' as above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to remove the modal from the DOM(I'm guessing you have it hidden somewhere anyway?), and then show a deep copied clone. For example:

```
// Remove the modal element from the rendered DOM, this should be
// done after you've attached any necessary event listeners
var $modalSource = $('#add-new').remove();

// Later on, when you need to pull up the modal
// Using clone(true) ensures that registered event listeners are also cloned
$modalSource.clone(true).modal('show');
```

Now, each time the modal is opened, it'll show a new clone instead of the original. This will return the opened modal to the state defined by it's HTML, so all fields will be in their original state. From the [jQuery .clone() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes. For performance reasons, the dynamic state of form elements (e.g., user data typed into input, and textarea or user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elemements. **The clone operation sets these fields to their default values as specified in the HTML.**

Removing the element from the DOM will ensure that selectors using any IDs still function as expected.

The best thing here is that this method can be used regardless of the elements contained within the modal. So even if you have inputs, textareas, selects and even custom elements, this will still work.

Based on the rest of the HTML & JS however, this answer may need to tweaked a little. So if you're still running into issues, post more details or provide a fiddle which illustrates your issue properly.

Comment: I was able to do what I needed with Bill'o's answer, but your answer here might have some relevance for another question I've asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687868/why-does-jquery-ajax-post-twice-here which involves a bug with my nested clicks.  If you get a chance and you have any thoughts on that one let me know.  And thanks for responding!

Comment: Actually the previously asked question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707553/modal-windows-and-binding-unbinding?lq=1

Comment: I'm headed off to work right now, but I'll take a look and let you know asap :D

Comment: That is true that it would work but regenerating the full markup each time seems a bit heavy no?

Comment: I've had cases where forms with a large variety of inputs need to be opened repeatedly in modals. In this case, it's easier to just clone the original rather than making sure that the values are cleared every time the modal opens/closes. So I agree that in the OPs case, this method is heavy. But if someone runs into this answer later and has a different use case, they might find this helpful :)